# How does the reputation system actually work?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, etiquette, up-votes

I seem to be confused about how the reputation system on these sites works precisely. I'm trying to advance so that I can make better use of these sites and provide more useful and valuable responses, but I feel like I'm not receiving reputation for upvoted posts and questions.

Is there a cap as to how many upvotes I need to get to receive reputation? Do I receive reputation for each upvote? Do I receive reputation if I get the answer? Do I only receive reputation if I get the answer?

I can't properly follow what actions I've made that get reputation, and I feel stuck at my current level where I can't be sure I'm efficiently helping people on the site according to site etiquette.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View a comprehensive answer at: [How does "Reputation" work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You can only gain (and lose) reputation on answers and questions that are NOT marked as Community Wiki. You also have a daily rep limit of 200 reputation points (not counting bounties won and accepted answers past the 200 point limit).

You gain 10 reputation for every upvote (unless you are at your rep limit, when in that case you will only earn enough rep to hit the limit).

You lose 2 reputation for every downvote (if you are above the 200 point rep limit, say 205, and you get a downvote, you are unable to recoup that last rep to get back to 205).

If you received a check mark for an accepted answer, you get a +15 reputation bonus.

If you are the one who set the checkmark on your own question, you will get +2 rep.

Comment: CW questions and answers still count for badges though, right?

Comment: Andy: yes, they still count for badges (much to the chagrin of some users).

Answer (score 0):

Just had trouble finding the current post that actually answers this question, so here's the link: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)